# Is it legal to completely retell a film in text?

Tags: copyright

Let's say I watched a film and I really liked it. Now I want to tell my subscribers on Facebook the entire plot of the film. I don't use the real script of the film. I create a post where I retell the film plot in my own words (but I don't change anything, the names are the same, everything is the same, it's just a conversion in textual form) and retell it completely. Is this action legal? Do I have any problems with copyright law?

Comment: Don't you think that depends first on what exactly you mean by "the entire plot of the film" or "just a conversion to textual form"?
There's a huge difference between the plot and the whole story, the story and the dialogue, before you start "retelling completely" all the stage directions and scene changes.

If you really did novelise an entire film, you might just claim purposes of study or review if you interspersed great long passages of comment…

At the end of the day, how much screen-space or reading time is this tome meant to take up?

Comment: Related, but not quite the same - I wonder what the [blinkenlights telnet ASCIImation](http://www.blinkenlights.nl/services.html#starwars) of Star Wars falls under ...

Answer (score 31):

This is known as "film novelization"(For example, the novelizations of the Star Wars movies are film novelizations, created under license), and is copyright infringement unless made under a license from the copyright holder.

Specifically, you would be making a derivative work of the original, by changing the medium. One of the rights provided by copyright is the right to control the transference from one medium into another.

This, in my (non-lawyer) opinion, is unlikely to be found as fair use. There are four test factors for determining fair use([source](https://fairuse.stanford.edu/overview/fair-use/four-factors/)), decided on a case by case basis:

**Transformative Character of the Derivative Work**: Unlikely to be found in your favor, as nothing is transformed ("I don't change anything, the name are the same, everything is the same, it's just a conversion to textual form").

**Nature of the Original Work**: A narrative entertainment film, thus unlikely to be found in your favor.

**Amount and Substantiality of the Portion Taken**: You've taken all of it; not in your favor.

**Effect on the Potential Market**: You are essentially providing a free version of what copyright holders can often charge for; negative effect on their potential market. Not in your favor.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how detailed does the novelization need to be? I doubt that the plot summary of a movie on Wikipedia counts as "film novelization" and infringes on someone's copyright.

Comment: It's not clear to me whether you are claiming Star wars novels were copyright infringements or just mention them as examples of film novelizations. I'm positive some like The Empire Strikes Back, written by Donald F. Glu, are perfectly copyright compliant. I'm not sure whether there are some fan fiction being sued for copyright infringement. I suppose it's probable, they were some. The copyright's holder, Lucasfilms (now part of Disney) is well known for being sue-happy and eager to protect the huge industry based on Star Wars merchandise.

Comment: @QuoraFeans Seems to me as if the Star Wars novelizations were used as an example of novelization. I think another important aspect is how recent the copyrighted material is, how much financial loss the copyright holder expects over the existance of the work, and how much of a reputation loss the company has to expect over suing someone. I imagine Lucasfilm suing a 14 year old boy over writing "The Adventures of Luke Skywalker" on his blog (do kids these days have blogs?) is bad optics.

Comment: Is it really considered film novelization if you aren't publishing it anywhere for public distribution and aren't making any money off of the publishing?

Comment: @QuoraFeans: Film novelization; I will clarify. The Star Wars novelizations are compliant, but that because they were created under license.

Comment: @MechMK1: Don't know of Lucasfilms suing minors. I wouldn't be surprised though. They sued Ronald Reagan for his Star Wars program, a micro-brewery selling Empire Beer, and Verizon for Android phones named "droid". Disney had asked some teenagers to remove social media posts. Don't know if there were legal ramifications.

Comment: So what about something like Cliff Notes and all the copycats thereof?  Did they only ever use public domain books or did they get permission from every work they summarized?

Comment: @Zibbobz : OP plans to post on Facebook, so this is not "aren't publishing it anywhere".  Also, the right under control is *copy*ing, not "making money from" -- noncommercial copying is still copying.

Comment: The first half of this answer's great, but some of the stuff in the second half feels biased toward making the issue seem more trivial.  For example, it seems weird to say that all of a film is taken by a novelization; I mean, Wikipedia's figures for [the "_Lord of the Rings_" movies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lord_of_the_Rings_(film_series)) claim that it cost 281 MUSD to produce them, with a box-office figure of 3 GUSD; presumably anyone who then pirated the full _Lord of the Rings_ book trilogy wouldn't have stolen that significant effort, nor averted its box-office success.

Comment: @Nat Are you using Mega-USD and Giga-USD as units!?

Comment: @QuoraFeans I can't imagine how "Empire Beer" would violate anyone's copyright, assuming they didn't try to brand it specifically as associated with Star Wars. Because I highly doubt you could trademark something as generic as "Empire", given that Games Workshop couldn't trademark their absolutely recognizable "Space Marines", because it was considered "Too Generic".

Comment: @MechMK1: yes, you are right. Just using the word 'empire' would not get anyone into legal trouble. But Empire brewery launched a Strikes Bock beer and used the sentence "May the hops be with you." in their marketing material. Anyway, anyone can sue you, if he feels like it. Winning is another issue, but here, at least I see some potential.

Comment: @QuoraFeans Agreed, although Disney could also pursue just to threaten a long-winded legal battle, even with terribly small chances of actually winning. By just continuing the battle and draining the brewery of any financial depots they may have, they would be able to force an out of court agreement, which I guarantee will be to Disney's advantage. The court system heavily favors whoever has the most money, not who is actually right.

Comment: @MechMK1: Fine, [fine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix): ~268 MiUSD and ~3 GiUSD.

Comment: @Nat I'm just very surprized by it. I've never seen anyone use the term "Mega-Dollar" :D

Comment: @MechMK1: Hah, yeah, does seem like folks tend to use "_million-USD_" and "_billion-USD_".

Comment: @Nat: The second half has the four factors that a U.S. court should consider in deciding whether or not something is fair use. Someone pirating the Lord of the Rings Trilogy does have a negative effect on the owner of the IP (which is the Tolkien Estate, which is still selling copies of LOTR). Not a big one, but the relative magnitude of the harm and the success of the work are not mentioned as something to take into account. Or to put it another way, the blockbuster and the box office bomb have the same legal protections.

Answer (score 21):

As an attorney with experience in copyright, I do not disagree with [sharur's answer](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/51297/31370) but find that it lacks some important considerations.

### The issue

To make sure we're clear, this is the question I'm discussing: *Can I retell, in my own words, a film's plot via social media?*

### What to Consider

- Legal analysis involves looking at relevant law, applying that law to the facts, and making what is often an unsatisfying and subjective determination. In other words, two courts given the same law and the same facts, can and do come to opposite conclusions.
- Newspapers and websites are full of book and movie reviews that summarize plot and characters. Under fair use, copyright law specifically allows for [commentary and criticism](https://www.americanbar.org/groups/gpsolo/publications/gp_solo/2011/september/fair_use_news_reviews/) of works without the permission of the copyright owner.
- There is a distinction between ideas and expression of those ideas. Copyright does not protect the idea but does protect the expression of the idea. For example, the idea to include a bank robbery in a film is not protected but the expression of that idea in a specific situation could be protected.
- The scènes à faire doctrine states that customary elements of a genre cannot be protected. For example, since it is practically obligatory in a sci-fi movie to have an alien, that element cannot be protected by copyright.
- The merger doctrine allows that when there are only a limited number of ways to say something, it can't be protected. For example, you can only say that it is sunny in so many ways. The idea of it being sunny and the expression, such as "it is sunny," merge and are not protected by copyright.
- Facts are not protected by copyright because they are not original. For example, saying that "Robert John Downey Jr. played a superhero in Iron Man" is a factual statement that is not protected.
- In a [case of a fan-created encyclopedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warner_Bros._Entertainment_Inc._v._RDR_Books) of Harry Potter books, the judge noted that "Reference works that [...] [aid] readers of literature generally should be encouraged rather than stifled." The fan lost the lawsuit because of ***long quotes*** from the books. Once those were removed, the fan published the encyclopedia (i.e., "Lexicon") for profit.
- And, of course, consider the elements of fair use as discussed by sharur.

### Bottom line

*This is not legal advice. If your question is part of a business, I would definitely hire a lawyer to provide detailed advice.*

There is a lot more wiggle room than people often assume under copyright. If you are well-meaning, enhance the value of the original work, and avoid long quotes, a judge is likely to like you a lot more.

Comment: That it's 'facebook' is the question imo. What would've happened if they had posted that Lexicon on Wiki *with* the long quotes (for free), instead of Facebook (for 'money')?

Comment: This wins in the nomination "The most useful answer that doesn't even attempt to answer the question".

Answer (score 8):

What you are describing very likely falls under what is called "fair use" and it is perfectly legal. In the U.S. there are four factors to consider, which you can find in the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use). Rest assured that a posting to Facebook retelling the story in your own words, inevitably with some commentary or criticism added, will certainly pass the test.

sharur's answer is ridiculous and completely wrong. Under no circumstances could what you are doing be considered a "novelization." You are doing what is known as a "recap." Recaps are done on non-profit and for-profit sites all the time for movies and TV shows. There are millions of them out there. Here's a [Clone Wars](https://www.cnet.com/news/star-wars-the-clone-wars-finale-episode-12-recap-ahsokas-adventure-ends-in-victory-and-death-maul-vader/) recap from two days ago on a for-profit site. And [another one](https://deadline.com/2020/05/star-wars-the-clone-wars-series-finale-may-the-4th-recap-ahsoka-tano-darth-vader-spoilers-1202924501/) for the same show, different for-profit site.

Comment: This would be the correct answer had the OP asked about putting together a brief summary of the main plot.  However, if they retell the story "completely", and achieve something that can be substituted for the fun of watching the film, then they risk being seen as a competitor rather than promoter of the film and copyright will be the main legal weapon used by the studio against them.

Comment: If you can find a case where a recap was successfully sued because it "substituted for the fun of watching the film," then you might have a point. There are no such cases. The exact words the OP says is "I create a post where I retell the film plot in my own words." That is a recap, which is done thousands of times a day all over the world, and it is perfectly legal. It does not have to be a brief summary, either.

Comment: Mohair, please describe the distance between a novelisation and a recap (in terms of the content).

Comment: What the OP is describing doesn't sound like a recap, which is usually just a short summary, not a detailed retelling.

Comment: @Barmar : But does the OP plan to write a 70000 words long novel, as a Facebook post?

Comment: @vsz Good point. Unless he's going to spread this over hundreds of posts, it does sound like just a summary.

Comment: @Mohair - The question is currently phrased as a pure hypothetical.  Perhaps I'm reading their "completely" too literally because they also mention a single visit to the cinema.

Comment: It's okay for folks to interpret the question differently.  Presumably different folks who visit this page and read that question will understand it slightly differently; answers that address various reasonable interpretations would seem constructive.

Comment: @Barmar [Facebook allows 60000+ characters per post](https://mashable.com/2012/01/04/facebook-character-limit/), so they would probably only need around 10 posts, not hundred of posts ;)

Comment: @AndrewT. I was thinking they would be writing each post at a single sitting. But I guess they could write the whole thing first, then paste it into a series of large posts.

Comment: This answer assumes things that are counter to the question posed.  sharur's answer is only ridiculous if you interpret the op saying "retell it completely" and "conversion to textual form" as meaning "a short summary" which hardly seems to be the correct interpretation. What the op describes absolutely would be a novelization and the medium (or number of posts) used to display the novelization is irrelevant.

Comment: @eps You are the one making assumptions. Here's a link to a random TV episode recap that is a complete retelling, a conversion to textual form, and not a short summary. It includes screen shots, direct quotes, and details the entire plot of the show. It's also on an ad supported site: https://ew.com/tv/recaps/the-challenge-season-35-episode-6/. By your measure, this is a "novelization." Except, it isn't. They should be  getting sued, right? Except, they aren't.

Answer (score 3):

*Let's say I read a book and I very liked it. Now I want to show all guests of my theatre the entire plot of the book. I don't just read the book aloud. I create a movie or play where I show the entire book plot visually with my own pictures and scenes (but I don't change anything, the names are the same, everything is the same, it's just a conversion to visual form) and retell it completely.*

You will undoubtedly have heard about movie studio's negotiating with book authors for permission to use the book, and about large sums that may have to be paid.

Suppose you are the one who wrote that book. You have skills ant talents, perhaps a professional education, and spent a lot of time and work in writing that book. While writing, you would need to pay for a home, food, clothing, may be a family, medical costs, save for retirement, and so on.

Would it be fair if Disney or Sony or whoever would turn your book into a movie and potentially earn millions of bucks without paying you anything?

Therefore, in a civilized society, we have laws that gives each one particular rights, such as copyrights.

Yes, the laws aren't perfect, and clever guys find loopholes to steal other's work under 'fair use', but your case where you use 'everything' and changes 'anything' looks like the textbook example for copyright.

Note however, that there is an important difference between 'completely retell in text' (question title) and 'tell the entire plot' (question text). You will not be able to retell the entire movie in text, as many aspects of a film rely on color, mimic, movements, backgrounds, camera positions, sharp and blurr images, and so on. Just the plot will not convey the entire movie, it will be just the plot. So if you were able to do a 'conversion of movie to text', it will infringe copyright. For example, if Homer would have converted two Hollywood movies into a best selling 30 thousand line text (over 1000 pages, needing two book volumes), truly completely retelling the movie in text.

But if you 'just' write down the plot of a 90 minute movie into 1000 words, it is only a miserly summary that will not at all threaten the commercial value of the original work.

Comment: So this is similar to the heap paradox... you remove sand grains one grain at a time from a heap of sand, when does it stop being a heap? Similarly, where do you draw the line between derivative work and summary? If a 1000 word summary is acceptable, then is a 1001 word summary suddenly not acceptable? Where is the line below which it's a summary, and above it a copyright infringement?

Comment: @vsz I don't know which paradox I am using, but the line is not at 1001 words, neither at 29.999 lines. Besides, I don't know how many words the average line has, depending on the language. Mr. H. used to write in an old greek dialect with 6 jambes per line Icorrect jargon?)

Comment: My point was, that on one extreme, there is a short plot summary like on wikipedia, which I'm sure everyone accepts as legal. And on the other extreme is a full novelization, which is definitely copyright infringement. But between those two extremes there is somewhere a grey area where it's impossible to tell to any certainty where it belongs.

Comment: @vsz Ok, on the other hand the original question seems to mention both extreme sides and not the large grey area in between