# Quora bots are copying a significant amount of Law Stack Exchange questions to Quora, without proper attribution

Tags: copyright

Quora users/bots are copying a significant amount of Stack Exchange questions to Quora, without proper attribution. It seems quite systematic.

For example:

- [Are passengers allowed to record the audio of their interactions with the US immigration officers when clearing the immigration as they enter the US?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/51408/31) was copied to Quora just a few seconds after to https://www.quora.com//unanswered/Are-passengers-allowed-to-record-the-audio-of-their-interactions-with-the-US-immigration-officers-when-clearing-the-immigration-as-they-enter-the-US?share=1
- [Is it legal to completely retell a film in text?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/51295/31) was copied to Quora: https://www.quora.com/Is-it-legal-to-completely-retell-a-film-in-text?share=1

This issue affects a few other Stack Exchange websites as well but I  thought that some users on Law Stack Exchange  may have the most suitable legal knowledge to find an appropriate course of action. Quora doesn't respond to my copyright violation complaints, and Stack Exchange employees aren't interested either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### This is not (necessarily) copyright violation

It's possible that Quora's usage falls within [Fair Use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use). At the very least, the argument could be made. If it does, then there is nothing that Stack Exchange or the OP can do.

### Stack Exchange can choose not to protect their copyright

Unlike trademarks, which lapse if not protected, copyright endures. Therefore Stack Exchange can pick and choose the copyright fights they want to get involved in and those they don't. If you have brought it to the attention of the copyright owner (or, in this case, licensee) and the copyright owner chooses not to act then you have done all you can and significantly more than you have to do.

### The OP has copyright

I note that one of the examples is your question. As the copyright holder, you are free to issue a DCMA takedown notice on Quora if you feel your copyright has been violated.

Comment: Thanks for the analysis!

Comment: And from SE's official standpoint: [A site (or scraper) is copying content from Stack Exchange. What should I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/200177/241919)